# u-sql script can not obtain scalar value from dataset

Tags: u-sql

In u-sql script I must extract a variable from file to a dataset and then use it to form a name of output file. How can I get the variable from the dataset?

In details.

I have 2 input files: csv file with a set of fields and a dictionary file. The 1st file has file name like ****ClintCode*****.csv. The 2nd file-dictionary has 2 fields with mapping: ClientCode - ClintCode2. My task is extract ClientCode value from the file name, get ClientCode2 from the dictionary, insert it as a field to output file (implemented), and, moreover, form the name of output file as ****ClientCode2****.csv.

Dictionary csv file has the content:

OldCode NewCode

6HAA  Alfa

CCVV  Beta

CVXX  gamma

?     Davis

The question is how to get ClientCode2 into scalar variable to write an expression for the output file?

```
DECLARE @inputFile string = "D:/DFS_SSC_Automation/Tasks/FundInfo/ESP_FAD_GL_6HAA_20170930.txt";  // '6HAA' is ClientCode here that mapped to other code in ClientCode_KVP.csv

DECLARE @outputFile string = "D:/DFS_SSC_Automation/Tasks/FundInfo/ClientCode_sftp_" +   // 'ClientCode' should be replaced with ClientCode from mapping in ClientCode_KVP.csv
                            DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyymmdd") + "_" +
                            DateTime.Now.ToString("HHmmss") + ".csv";

DECLARE @dictionaryFile string = "D:/DFS_SSC_Automation/ClientCode_KVP.csv";


@dict =
    EXTRACT [OldCode] string,
            [NewCode] string
    FROM @dictionaryFile
    USING Extractors.Text(skipFirstNRows : 1, delimiter : ',');

@theCode =
    SELECT Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(@inputFile).IndexOf([OldCode]) >= 0 ? 1 : 3 AS [CodeExists],
           [NewCode]
    FROM @dict
    UNION
    SELECT *
    FROM(
        VALUES
        (
            2,
            ""
        )) AS t([CodeExists],[NewCode]);

@code =
    SELECT [NewCode]
    FROM @theCode
ORDER BY [CodeExists]
FETCH 1 ROWS;


@GLdata = 
    EXTRACT [ASAT] string,
    [ASOF] string,
    [BASIS_INDICATOR] string,
    [CALENDAR_DATE] string,
    [CR_EOP_AMOUNT] string,
    [DR_EOP_AMOUNT] string,
    [FUND_ID] string,
    [GL_ACCT_TYPE_IND] string,
    [TRANS_CLIENT_FUND_NUM] string
FROM @inputFile
USING Extractors.Text(delimiter : '|', skipFirstNRows : 1);

// Prepare output dataset

@FundInfoGL =
    SELECT "" AS [AccountPeriodEnd],
           "" AS [ClientCode],
           [FUND_ID] AS [FundCode],
           SUM(GL_ACCT_TYPE_IND == "A"? System.Convert.ToDecimal(DR_EOP_AMOUNT) : 0) AS [NetValueOtherAssets],
           SUM(GL_ACCT_TYPE_IND == "L"? System.Convert.ToDecimal(CR_EOP_AMOUNT) : 0) AS [NetValueOtherLiabilities],
           0.0000 AS [NetAssetsOfSeries]
    FROM @GLdata
    GROUP BY FUND_ID;


// NetAssetsOfSeries calculation

@FundInfoGLOut =
    SELECT [AccountPeriodEnd],
           [NewCode] AS [ClientCode],
           [FundCode],
           Convert.ToString([NetValueOtherAssets]) AS [NetValueOtherAssets],
           Convert.ToString([NetValueOtherLiabilities]) AS [NetValueOtherLiabilities],
           Convert.ToString([NetValueOtherAssets] - [NetValueOtherLiabilities]) AS [NetAssetsOfSeries]
    FROM @FundInfoGL
    CROSS JOIN @code;


// Output

OUTPUT @FundInfoGLOut
TO @outputFile
USING Outputters.Text(outputHeader : true, delimiter : '|', quoting : false);
```

Comment: have you tried anything? If yes then post that code please.

Comment: What dataset? What variable? What output file? Show some info on what you're trying to do. This is too vague.

Comment: Hi @OksanaMikolenko, could you please edit the question instead of posting the details in the comments? That makes it better readable. And are you able to post the u-sql code as well, so we can see what you tried and help you solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can't.  Please see [Convert Rowset variables to scalar value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40094944/convert-rowset-variables-to-scalar-value?rq=1).

You may still be able to achieve your ultimate goal in a different manner.  Please consider re-writing your post with clear & concise language, small dataset, expected output, and a very minimal amount of code needed to repro - remove all details and nuances that aren't necessary to create a test case.

Answer (score 0):

As David points out: You cannot assign query results to scalar variables.

However, we have a dynamic partitioned output feature in private preview right now that will give you the ability to generate file names based on column values. Please contact me if you want to try it out.

Comment: Hi @MichaelRys, thank you, but I can not find any e-mail in your profile that I would write you to. I would very appreciate if you email me to oksana.mikolenko@gmail.com or provide some contact details.